# SQL new column value based from another column in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have a table with invoice sales lines and I am trying to make a query to generate a new column with the value from another column transaction in the same table. Already tried with CASE and subqueries, but the columns fills the value when meets the criteria:

[image]

The query is:

```
select [No_], 
[Document No_], 
Quantity, 
[Line Discount _], 
[Unit Price], 
[new_column] = (select si.Quantity where CONVERT(decimal,si.[Unit Price]) = 0 )

from [Sales Invoice Lines] si
```

But what I really need is to have the new_column values in the transaction that the Unit Price is != 0.

What I am trying to accomplish is to get the Quantity values to the transactions that the Unit Price column has value and the No_ is the same:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: So use `WHERE si.[Unit Price] <> 0`. You don't need to convert anything. It's not really clear what you're trying to do, though - shouldn't your subquery JOIN to the original table so that you're getting the right row's value?

Comment: [mre] [ask] [Help] [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)

Comment: You need to explain the logic behind. Which numbers should be stored there? What to do if there are further rows having the same no_ or document_no?

Comment: You also forgot to tag your DBMS

Comment: Hi @JonasMetzler, this a sales invoice line table, it represents every line of product within a invoice,  the No_ field are the products and the products with unit price 0 are given free with a promotion, and what I am trying to do is to create a new column where stores the quantity of the products are giving for free, but need to be related with the one where sold in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to go back in time and populate this column when generating the free sales line(s).
But now that that horse have left the barn, you can fetch them in a correlated subquery:

```sql
select ProductNO, Doc, Qty, Discount, Price
, CASE WHEN price > 0 THEN (select SUM(qty) FROM invoice_line il WHERE il.Doc= i.Doc AND il.Price = 0 AND il.ProductNO= i.ProductNO) END AS new_column
FROM invoice_line i
...
```

I'm guessing that production number of the free line should match the product number of the paid line, since you didn't bother mention it. This will also not work if multiple of the same paid products exist

Comment: Absolutely perfect.!!